# FitNesse: Slim test with no assertions fails after getting 4xx/5xx response code

Tags: fitnesse

I'm using `hsac-fitnesse-fixtures` for FitNesse tests.

When I started working on negative API tests I noticed FitNesse test suite fails if JSON HTTP Test fixture receives 4xx/5xx response, while no assertions were made in the actual test:

[image: ![example 1](https://imgur.com/a/Kl7yqch)]

Adding assertions where we're actually waiting for 4xx/5xx response code does not make the difference: the assertion passes, but the test still fails.

[image]

I'm trying to find out how to make such negative tests pass. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it's necessary to add `|reject|` keyword before `|get from|` or any other HTTP action in *hsac-fitnesse-fixtures* to perform a negative test.

More details can be found in project's [GitHub Issues](https://github.com/fhoeben/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures/issues/19) and [FitNesse Script Table Keywords](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.FullReferenceGuide.UserGuide.WritingAcceptanceTests.SliM.ScriptTable).